# Display image using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am very new to angular 2 
I am stuck here where i have to display an image for which I'm using relative path­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
<img src="./../images/publicVideo1.PNG">
```

but getting the below error

```
null:1 GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

The above is the app structure where I have image in images folder which I'm trying to access from public-videos.component.html

I dont understand where I'm wrong
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think you should try `<img src="./images/publicVideo1.PNG">` if this img is written inside app.componant.html

Answer (score 6):

create one dir `assets` in src directory. and move images directory into assets and then you can access image like that. image not found in app folder because  we need to set path in assets[] block in the .angular-cli.json. we need set path into asset block we access it. does this help.

```
<img src="../../assets/images/publicVideo1.PNG">
```

**angular-cli.json**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this `<img src="./src/app/images/publicVideo1.PNG">`

Comment: `../` is precisely identical to `./../`.

Comment: check in the inspect element , open the path in the new tab.

Comment: if its not come ,,check like this http://localhost:4200/src/app/images/publicVideo1.PNG

Comment: did you try check in the inspect element? check my above comment

Comment: Yes
I have checked the inpect element and have opened it i the new tab

Comment: so are you seeing the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this one here

```
<img [src]="defaultProfilePic" />
```

and in your component

```
defaultProfilePic: string ='assets/profile.png';
```

if this doesn't work it is because of the relative path you used. If you are using visualCode it will help you finding the exact path.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the path relative to your `index.html`. If your `index.html` is inside the `src` folder, then try this:

`<img src="./app/images/publicVideo1.PNG">`

Comment: It isnt coming that way

Comment: What is the location of your index.html?

Comment: It is in src folder and in app folder level