# Angular - Images won't display with relative path

Tags: html, image, angular, angular-cli

I am using relative path to display images in my application. It was working perfectly until I update my application to the latest version of Angular (4.1.3).
I don't have any errors and my images don't display anymore.

I have in `app.component.html` :

```
<img src="/src/images/settings.png" />
```

My app structure :

```
► e2e
► node_modules
► obj
▼ src
    ▼ app
        app.component.html
        app.component.ts
        app.module.ts
    ► assets
    ► environments
    ▼ images
        settings.png
    index.html
    main.ts
    polyfills.ts
    styles.css
    tsconfig.app.json
    tsconfig.spec.json
    typing.d.ts
.angular-cli.json
.editorconfig
.gitignore
karma.conf.js
package.json
protactor.conf.js
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

I tried many paths as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472332/display-image-using-angular-2) but none is working. And the difference with this question is that I do not have any error, my application is working, the images are just not displaying. 
And the weird thing is that it was working perfectly before I update my application.

Any ideas where this might come from ?

Comment: You should add `angular-cli` as a tag. I think it's relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using angular-cli. Make sure you have `images` in your `app.assets[]` block in the `.angular-cli.json` so that it's packaged up the same way your assets directory is. Then, change the path to `images/settings.png`

Alternatively, you can move the `images` directory *inside* the `assets` folder which should already be packaged.

Comment: Both methods are working, thank you !
Do you have an idea why it was working before the update ? This kind of mistake has nothing to do with angular versions, right?

Comment: What version were you updating from? I'm not sure what would have changed - I've always made sure to add anything I want in the output to that array (otherwise it's not packaged up for the app)

Comment: I was at Angular 4.0 and I ran an npm update, it updated a lot of modules ; so I can't remember every module which was updated, but I went from angular 4.0 to 4.1.3
I'll be more careful in the future, thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your app tree, wouldn't be `images/settings.png` ?

Your *images* folder is at the same height than *index.html*

Comment: No It's not working, and this path was working fine before I updated my application to the latest version of angular, and in my example I am calling my image from `app.component.html`

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the same issue in class with students,

When we did an ng build, and saw the dist folder didn't contain the images folder we created, looked around and found that an asset folder existed.

put the images into the assets folder and followed the path for that, the image appeared in the dist, and then the images popped up in serve.

Hope that helps others in the future.

(for version 15)